# arules substitution of item values in R

Tags: r, transactions, rules, apriori, market-basket-analysis

So, i'm trying to make arules work with my data, I have the transaction_ID, Item_name and Item_ID. But if I call the apriori function for the item_name and transaction_ID, is too slow but if I call it with item_id and transaction_ID is really fast. So, is there a way to create the rules with item_id and then substitute the ids for it real name ?
here is a code example to work with:

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)

products <- c(1,1,1,3,4,5,6,4)
transaction_id <- c(2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
dataset <- data.frame(products ,transaction_id)
dataset
transaction <- as(split(dataset[,"products"],dataset[,"transaction_id"]), "transactions")

rule <- apriori(transaction, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.8))

inspect(rule)

products_id <- c(1,3,4,5,6)
names <- c("nail","Black Hammer 127","White desk 12","green desk","pink car")

cod <- data.frame(products = products_id, names)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to replace the item labels in the transactions using the function `itemLabels`:

```
itemLabels(transaction)
  [1] "1" "3" "4" "5" "6"
itemLabels(transaction) <- c("nail","Black Hammer 127","White desk 12","green desk","pink car")
rule <- apriori(transaction, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.8))
inspect(rules)
      lhs                                 rhs                support   confidence
 [1]  {Black Hammer 127}               => {nail}             0.3333333 1 
 ...
```

`split` is rather slow. The example in `?transactions` says about using split:

```
## Note: This is very slow for large datasets. It is much faster to 
## read transactions in this format from disk using read.transactions() 
## with format = "single".
```

Comment: That worked for this example but for my real data, itemLabels() is accusing . Error in `dimnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) :  length of dimnames does not equal the dimension of the object.. In the read.transaction(), my data must be a transaction file, but i can't create it

Comment: Maybe you have items that never occur in the data and thus the transactions have fewer items. Also, the order might be different. Here is a more robust way to replace the item labels: `itemLabels(transaction) <- cod$names[match(itemLabels(transaction), cod$products)]`

Comment: Yeah, you were right, it was the size. Thanks for the advice! Now, i will just to learn how to create a readable transaction file.